# hibernate composite key mapping foreign key issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

this is my [mysql db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D8Jb.png)

user.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")

public class user 
{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

   private int uid;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="user")
   private Set<order> orders = new HashSet<order>();
   //
   setter ,getter  ,and other 
}
```

order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`order`")
public class order 
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int oid;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="oid", referencedColumnName="oid" )
   private Set<orderitem> orderitems = new HashSet<orderitem>();

   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="uid")
   private user user ;

   /////
   setter ,getter and other

}
```

orderitem.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderitem")
public class orderitem 
{
   @EmbeddedId
   private orderitem_PK PK; //composite key

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="oid", referencedColumnName="oid" ,insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private order order;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="pid", referencedColumnName="pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private product products ;

   ////
   setter,getter and other
}
```

orderitem_PK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class orderitem_PK implements Serializable
{

    private int oid;
    private int pid;
    public orderitem_PK() {}

    public orderitem_PK(int oid, int pid) {
        this.oid = oid;
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    // equals, hashCode

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.hashCode();
    }
```

and last product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class product 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int pid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name="pid", referencedColumnName="pid" )
    private Set<orderitem> orderitems = new HashSet<orderitem>();

     //////////
        setter,getter and other

}
```

it is a online shopping page

I'm trying to insert data by this code

```
             order order = new order();
             order.setUser(user);
             order.setOrdertotal(product.getPrice());

             Date dt = new Date();
             DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
             String nowTime = df.format(dt);
             java.sql.Timestamp buydate = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(nowTime); 

             order.setOrderdate(buydate);

             /// delete this part will work 
             orderitem orderitem = new orderitem();
             orderitem.setOrder(order);
             orderitem.setProducts(product);
             orderitem.setQuantity(product.getQuantity());
             orderitem.setPrice(product.getPrice());

             ////

             session.save(order);
             session.save(orderitem);
```

encounter some error.

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class Model.orderitem

when I only save user and order part the code is work .

after add save orderitem code , the problem occurred.

i think composite key mapping foreign key is wrong.

but I don't know how to fix it .

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map both oid and pid in your EmbeddedId using **@MapsId.**
@MasId provides the mapping for an EmbeddedId primary key or a simple primary key of the parent entity.
Make the following changes in your orderItem Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderitem")
public class orderitem 
{
   @EmbeddedId
   private orderitem_PK PK; //composite key

   @ManyToOne
   @MapsId("oid") // maps the order id attribute of embedded id
   @JoinColumn(name="oid", referencedColumnName="oid" ,insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private order order;

   @ManyToOne
   @MapsId("pid") // maps the product id attribute of embedded id
   @JoinColumn(name="pid", referencedColumnName="pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private product products ;

   ////
   setter,getter and other
}
```

Comment: thanks , but i try your way and still occurre problem "Could not set field value [9] value by reflection : [class Model.orderitem_PK.oid] setter of Model.orderitem_PK.oid " and the value[] will accumulate each time I try , it's weird

Comment: You need to have getters and setters of oid and pid in orderitem_PK if you want to set these fields using @MapsId.

Comment: i do have getters and setters in orderitem_PK . i just forget to say it

Comment: Also set orderitem_PK in your orderItem object. orderitem.setOrderitem_PK(new Orderitem_PK());